# Linux command to remove lines containing a duplicated value in a text file?

Tags: terminal, command

If I have a text file with the following form

```
1  1
1  3
3  4
2  2
5  7
...
```

Is there a Linux command that can give me the following result?

```
1  3
3  4
5  7
...
```

So, I want to delete the lines `1  1` and `2  2`.

Comment: `awk '$1 != $2' file`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use something like:

```
awk '$1!=$2{print}' inputfilename
```

or the slightly less verbose (thanks to `ooga`):

```
awk '$1!=$2' inputfilename
```

which uses the "missing action means `print`" feature of `awk`.

Both these `awk` commands print lines where the columns don't match, and throw away everything else.

Comment: Why the inverted logic?  Why not just `awk '$1 != $2 {print}'`?  There's really no need for the `next` here.